# ¿Cómo cambio el tamaño de un <asp:CheckBox>, estoy programando en asp.net en una plantilla de DotNetNuke?

Tags: css, asp.net

cómo le puedo cambiar el tamaño original que trae un control CheckBox de asp.net **asp:CheckBox**, ya intente colocarle un CSS de esta forma

```
.checksAprob{
    transform: scale(1.5); 
 }

<div class="chbxAprobaciones">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="AprobComercial" runat="server" CssClass="checksAprob" />
</div>
```

pero no me funcionó, alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que cuando ya se renderiza ese `asp:CheckBox` es un `input`, por lo cual debes de aplicar la clase al `input` interno

```css
.checksAprob input {
    transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```